# How do you find the other solution of x+x=2 for the group Z/6 given 1 solution?

Tags: group-theory

While watching this stuff about galois theory (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGThq0bUHCo) i learnt that if we know one of the solutions (1 or 3) to x+x=2 for group Z/4 we can use a group automorphism fixing 2 to find the other solution.

I wanted to see if it worked for other things like x+x=2 for the group Z/6 but i cannot find any automorphism fixing 2 that would map one of the solutions (1,4) to the other. Do you need some variation of this group automorphism function to solve this problem or am i missing something? My understanding of an automorphism is that f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b) so the identity maps to itself, inverses map to inverses and each element is paired to a different element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An automorphism of a cyclic group can be determined by sending a generator of the group to another generator. $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ has exactly two generators, $1$ and $5$. The automorphism sending $1 \to 1$ is the identity map, and the automorphism sending $1 \to 5$ does not fix $2$.

As you helpfully pointed out in the comments, there is a second solution ($x=1$ and $x=4$) but there is no automorphism sending $1 \to 4$.  Rather you want to find the extra solutions by solving $c+c=0$; then if $x$ is a solution, you can get the others by looking at $x+c$.

Comment: Im confused i thought 0 was the identity thing

Comment: oh right i think im way out of my depth here but y doesnt 4+4 solve the equation?

Comment: lol, is there anything that would work as some sort of transformation to get 4 from 1? Or is there no way to do that